# How to log requests in ktor http client?

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, ktor

I got something like this:

```
private val client = HttpClient {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = GsonSerializer()
    }
    install(ExpectSuccess)
}
```

and make request like

```
  private fun HttpRequestBuilder.apiUrl(path: String, userId: String? = null) {
    header(HttpHeaders.CacheControl, "no-cache")
    url {
        takeFrom(endPoint)
        encodedPath = path
    }
}
```

but I need to check request and response body, is there any way to do it? in console/in file?

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve this with the `Logging` feature.

First add the dependency:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktor_version"
```

Then install the feature:

```
private val client = HttpClient {
   install(Logging) {
      logger = Logger.DEFAULT
      level = LogLevel.ALL
   }
}
```

**Bonus:**

If you need to have multiple `HttpClient` instances throughout your application and you want to reuse some of the configuration, then you can create an extension function and add the common logic in there. For example:

```
fun HttpClientConfig<*>.default() {
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.DEFAULT
        level = LogLevel.ALL
    }

    // Add all the common configuration here.
}
```

And then initialize your `HttpClient` like this:

```
private val client = HttpClient {
   default()
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this but I cant seem to see the request and response logs :(

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones ktor has quite poor error handling. For example, if you have to serialize a class for the request's `body` and you haven't provided a (correct) serializer for this class, then the request won't be sent and you won't see any logs. Perhaps you have configured something else wrong in your `HttpClient` but for me issues with the serializers were the most frequent reasons for not seeing any logs.

Comment: I see. I am not using any serialization though. So that shouldn't be the case. I am trying to do this in android and the only way I was about to make the logging work is to use `OkHttp` as the engine for  `HttpClient` and add the `LoggingInterceptor` in the `OkHttp`. I wonder whether just adding the logging itself should have enabled the logging?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones Are you sure that your request is sent properly though? The above example works for me on Android without `OkHttp`. If there's any exception thrown in your `HttpClientConfig` block then the request won't be sent and you won't see any logs.

Comment: The request is sent and i recieve a response. I just don't see the logs. maybe im doing it wrong. Do you have some simple project I could look at? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones Well, in my project the setup is exactly like the "bonus" part of my answer and then I simply use the `client` instance like this: `client.get<String> { ... }`

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing that @ArchieG.Quiñones is experiencing. I cant' see the logs while making a request through Android.

Comment: @JeffreyNyauke I eventually was able to make it work. But there is another problem. Although the request are now logged, the reqeust body isn't logged at all. I cant find the link for the issue but I believe it would be fixed by the next release.

Comment: Internally Ktor uses slf4j (for jvm). So in order to use the default logger you have to import log4j too: implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.30")

Comment: I can't get Logging to be a recognized symbol. Can you please show me ALL of the #implementation items and import items required for "Logging" to be a recognized symbol?

Comment: When I keep the `native` in the dependency, my grade sync fails in my KMP project. So I had just use `implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"` instead.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this as well. I switched to using the [Ktor OkHttp client](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/engines.html#okhttp) as I'm familiar with the logging mechanism there.

Update your `pom.xml` or `gradle.build` to include that client (copy/paste from the Ktor site) and also add the [OkHttp Logging Interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) (again, copy/paste from that site). Current version is `3.12.0`.

Now configure the client with

```
val client = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    engine {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level = Level.BODY
        addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Regardless of which client you use or framework you are on, you can implement your own logger like so:

```
private val client = HttpClient {
    // Other configurations...
    install(Logging) {
        logger = CustomHttpLogger()
        level = LogLevel.BODY
    }
}
```

Where `CustomHttpLogger` is any class that implements the ktor Logger interface, like so:

```
import io.ktor.client.features.logging.Logger

class CustomHttpLogger(): Logger {
    override fun log(message: String) {
        Log.d("loggerTag", message) // Or whatever logging system you want here
    }
}
```

You can read more about the Logger interface in [the documentation here](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/features/logging.html) or in the [source code here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/master/ktor-client/ktor-client-features/ktor-client-logging/common/src/io/ktor/client/features/logging/Logger.kt)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, looks like Default logger uses slf4j, which does nothing on Android. I have reported an issue, let's see for their feedback: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1219

Comment: Why does it show a warning: `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"`

Answer (score 3):

For Ktor client logging on Android, besides `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:2.3.4")` dependency you also need to add SLF4J `implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.9")`.

Without SLF4J, you won't see any Ktor HTTP logs in Logcat (using provided `DEFAULT` or `ANDROID` Ktor logger). Only this warning:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

If you are using Timber (or similar), after adding SLF4J, you have to implement a custom logger like this:

```
install(Logging) {
    logger = object : Logger {
        override fun log(message: String) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Timber.d(message) else Timber.i(message)
        }
    }
    level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) LogLevel.BODY else LogLevel.INFO
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**A custom structured log can be created with the** `HttpSend` [plugin](https://ktor.io/docs/http-send.html)

**Ktor 2.x**:

```
client.plugin(HttpSend).intercept { request ->
    val call = execute(request)
    val response = call.response
    val durationMillis = response.responseTime.timestamp - response.requestTime.timestamp
    Log.i("NETWORK", "[${response.status.value}] ${request.url.build()} ($durationMillis ms)")
    call
}
```

**Ktor 1.x:**

```
client.config {
    install(HttpSend) {
        intercept { call, _ ->
            val request = call.request
            val response = call.response
            val durationMillis = response.responseTime.timestamp - response.requestTime.timestamp
            Log.i("NETWORK", "[${response.status.value}] ${request.url} ($durationMillis ms)")
            call
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we should handle the `response` in `HttpReceivePipeline`. We could clone the origin response and use it for logging purpose:

```
scope.receivePipeline.intercept(HttpReceivePipeline.Before) { response ->
    val (loggingContent, responseContent) = response.content.split(scope)

    launch {
        val callForLog = DelegatedCall(loggingContent, context, scope, shouldClose = false)
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

The example implementation could be found here: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/00369bf3e41e91d366279fce57b8f4c97f927fd4/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/src/io/ktor/client/features/observer/ResponseObserver.kt
 and would be available in next minor release as a client feature.

btw: we could implement the same scheme for the request.